# WP plugin to measure social media followers of different sites

Tags: wordpress, social-media

I am building a site, each page of which has profiles of certain organizations. One organization featured per page, sort of a bio on each etc.

I am looking for a way (plugin?) to list how many social media followers each organization has. This info would necessarily vary on each page.

The problem with most social media plugins I've seen is that the parameters are universally set for the widget as a whole.

Is there a way to get this sort of data onto a specific page?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can display social media followers of each organization in different pages. You need to create function and provide arguments for each organization separately. 
See my plugin as an example:
http://wordpress.org/plugins/social-media-followers-counter/

This plugin, however, do not display social statics separately. You can customize it to fulfill your requirement.